# What does the term "legal connection" mean?

Tags: terminology

I see a [lot](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=legal%20is%3aq) of [questions](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/13287/is-this-assembly-legal) and [answers](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/13353/13908) asking if certain builds or connections are "legal".

As a complete novice with little understanding of LEGO terminology what does that phrase mean? If certain things are legal does that also mean that mean that other things are prohibited? What/who defines LEGO legality?

The question referenced in the comments doesn't answer my question because it doesn't define what "legality" actually is. The referenced question provides a few examples of "illegal" connections but because of my knowledge (or lack of it) I'm still unable to determine what actually is "legal".

Comment: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7645/what-are-some-illegal-lego-combinations

Comment: If you connect Lego pieces in certain ways, the Lego police will come and put you in Lego jail.